# Comparing two files at end of line in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I would like to compare two files and get the output of matching string in one of the files at the end of the line:

Let's say I have two files:-

file1:

```
xyzabcdef
xyz
abcdefghi
```

file2:

```
fghjkl
wertyu
abcdef
```

I could do something like this:

```
grep -Fif file2 file1
```

This gives me the following output:

```
xyzabcdef
abcdefghi
```

This is because abcdef in file2 matches both of those lines in file1. However, what I would like is to just compare the end of the line in file1 to those in file2. So, I would like output to be:

```
xyzabcdef
```

Is there some magic command that will let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending Lars's solution which I think the best option. Simply use the following:

```
cat -E file2  | grep -if - file1
```

The trick is to use `-E` option of `cat` to append `$` at the end of each line. Then read the pattern from stdin using `-` option of grep. Also you have to use regex matching, so I removed the `-F`.

Comment: Thank you. All answers actually worked but this one seems to be the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

I would append `$` to each line of file2 and use the command `grep -if file2 file1`.

The `$` is a regex and means "match at the end of the line". The option `-F` would use fixed string mode that is incompatible with regex, thus omit this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by reading each line in `file2` and using each line as a search term for `grep` anchoring the term to the end of line with `$`, e.g.:

```
$ while read -r line; do grep "${line}$" file1; done <file2
xyzabcdef
```